# Pascal File Handling

Tags: file-io, pascal

I'm using free Pascal 2.6.4 and I created this code. It's a program that asks for number which represents line in file. Everything works except one thing. When I want to display 1. line it stops with "exitcode 217". **Why?**

```
Program FileTruncate;

uses
  SysUtils;
  label znova;

const
  filename = 'C:\Users\KVIKY\Desktop\Pascal\Projects\FileHandling\test.txt';

var
  myfile: text;
  line: string;
  counter:integer;
  position:double;


begin

 znova:
  Writeln('Zadaj cislo riadku: ');
  Readln(position);
  if position=0 then exit;
  if position>26 then exit;
  Assign(myfile, filename);
  Reset(myfile);
  counter:=0;
 Repeat
  inc(counter);
  readln(myfile);
  until counter = position-1;
  readln(myfile, line);
  Close(myfile);
  writeln(line);
  Writeln('Stlacte enter pre pokracovanie.');
  Writeln('Zadajte 0 pre ukoncenie programu.');
  readln;
  goto znova;
end.
```

Comment: Why have you made `position` a double? You can't read a file to line 12.5 or 9.7; you can only read whole lines. Make it an integer, just like `counter`. Then use the debugger to step through the code to see what exactly is happening and what variable values are when the error occurs. Then get rid of the `goto` that has been discouraged for decades and build a proper loop  instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for advice. I didn't saw DOUBLE but it's corrected. Actually I found mistake by myself. Because in if position=1 i had readline twice, so It jumped one line down! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when `position` is 1, your `repeat-until` condition will never be met (because your `counter=1` and `position-1` is zero, so `counter = position-1` will never happen).

counter represents the line *before* the target, so...

Instead, you could initialize differently:

`counter := -1`

or, better, change your loop to a `while`-`do`:

`while counter < position-1 do`

because you have a `readln` within the loop